# Error while trying to connect to local router on artifactory 7.4.3

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

When executing the Artifactory version 7.4.3, I see below error, and I changed as per the [jfrog artifactory could not validate router error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423174/jfrog-artifactory-could-not-validate-router-error/60501409#60501409)    but still same error, can someone please advise. Thanks.

```
failed initializing Access client: Cluster join: Service registry ping failed; context deadline exceeded. last error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Get http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
```

System.Yaml file:

```
shared:
## Security Configuration
security:
    ## Maximum time to wait for key files (master.key and join.key)
    #bootstrapKeysReadTimeoutSecs: 120
    ## Join key value for joining the cluster (takes precedence over 'joinKeyFile')
    #joinKey: "<Your joinKey>"
    ## Join key file location
    #joinKeyFile: "<For example: JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key>"
    ## Master key file location
    ## Generated by the product on first startup if not provided
    #masterKeyFile: "<For example: JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/master.key>"

## Node Settings
node:
    ## Default: auto resolved by startup script
    ip: 172.24.18.44
    ## Sets this node as primary in HA installation
    #primary: true
    ## A unique id to identify this node.
    ## Default: auto generated at startup.
    #id: "art1"
    ## Sets this node as part of HA installation
    #haEnabled: true
```

Below is the error from router-service.log, i don't find the shared node ip in router-service.log

```
[join_executor.go:148          ] [main                ] - Cluster join: Retry 120: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Could not parse error from service registry, status code: 404
```

after updating the system.yaml file:

```
shared:
  node:
     ip: 172.24.18.44
```

router-service.log

```
2020-05-19T04:36:48.559Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [660aef287984ef11] [bootstrap.go:73               ] [main                ] - JFrog Router IP: 172.24.18.44
```

2020-05-19T04:36:48.562Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [660aef287984ef11] [bootstrap.go:165              ] [main                ] - System configuration encryption report:
shared.newrelic.licenseKey: does not exist in the config file
shared.security.joinKeyFile: file '/apps/artifactory-pro-7.4.3/var/etc/security/join.key' - already encrypted
2020-05-19T04:36:48.563Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [660aef287984ef11] [bootstrap.go:78               ] [main                ] - JFrog Router Service ID: jfrou@01e8nfmn4nqdr5ay9q2225f6v6
2020-05-19T04:36:48.563Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [660aef287984ef11] [bootstrap.go:79               ] [main                ] - JFrog Router Node ID: tsrca24l
2020-05-19T04:37:22.945Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [660aef287984ef11] [join_executor.go:148          ] [main                ] - Cluster join: Retry 5: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Get http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/system/ping: context deadline exceeded

Comment: Can you share the `system.yaml` you have created. Also please check in router logs what `shared.node.ip` did it pick up?

Comment: please see above updated details of system.yaml and router-service.log

Comment: what type of installation? (docker-compose, debian, rpm, tar.gz)

Comment: @kumar the system.yaml is not accurate. The  node section should be  indented below  shared as below:

Comment: Thank you Prasanna, its working after removing the security from system.yaml but one quick question, when I try to stop artifactory*./artifactory.sh stop) it won't stop, please see above updated screen shot.Please advise.Thank you.

Comment: Prasanna, it was working first time only after updating the system.yaml file  when stop and start the artifactory it is throwing the same connection refused error, can you please advise.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kumar the `system.yaml` is not accurate. The `node` section should be indented under shared as below. You  can  remove the security section completely.

```
shared:
    node:
        ip: <your ip>
```

Comment: Prasanna, it was working first time only after updating the system.yaml file when stop and start the artifactory it is throwing the same connection refused error, can you please advise.Thanks

Comment: The above `system.yaml` you are embedding  will not set the ip properly for the system. Unless your host is set to return this ip. Can  you confirm  that `shared.node.ip` is set as per  the `system.yaml` above? To confirm that you can look at the  router-service.log where it  prints the  IP address it took.

Comment: please see above updated router logs, can you please advise how to set IP properly in system.yaml if my system.yaml set up is wrong?Thanks.

Comment: when I do hostname -i it returns the same IP

Comment: IP is set properly,  it does seem that  is the issue anymore. What OS and installer type are you using? After artifactory.sh stop, Can you  check  what services continue to run even after stop. Perform  `ps -ef  | grep jfrog` to get the list.

Comment: its working now with your changes, Thank you so much!!