# How to get artifactory to use IPV4 instead of IPV6

Tags: redhat, artifactory, ipv4, centos8

I'm trying to install Artifactory on CentOS 8.  While the installation proceeds reasonably, the configuration ends up binding to IPV6 rather than IPV4 interfaces.  This of course seems to make it inaccessible on the IPV4 network.  I've tried putting an IPV4 address in var/etc/system.yaml as described in: [jfrog artifactory could not validate router error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423174/jfrog-artifactory-could-not-validate-router-error)
without effect.

I've tried disabling the IPV6 interface, but that doesn't seem to be suffient.

Any hints would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Per https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-force-artifactory-to-run-with-ipv4-only-on-an-dual-stack-kubernete-cluster/

Add:

```
  shared:
      extraJavaOpts: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

to `system.yaml`.