# Unable to Access Jfrog UI - jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.21.5

Tags: windows, artifactory

I have installed the recent patch (jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.21.5-windows.zip) and post installation, I am not able to reach the UI of Jfrog. Below is the screen, that I am getting. Is this a known issue?

[image: JFrog UI Not Available]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maryo - I think you are hit by this issue: [jfrog artifactory could not validate router error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423174/jfrog-artifactory-could-not-validate-router-error)

Can you update your system.yaml (will be in var/etc/ folder) with the following and try? If there is no system.yaml, add one with user `artifactory` as the owner of the file.

```
shared:
    node:
        ip: <your ipv4 IP>
```